# Power Analysis Weighted Data

Tags: statistical-power, weighted-sampling

Suppose an outcome depends on the intensity of a treatment intervention $\pi$, where $\pi \in [0,1]$. Given intensity of treatment $\pi$, the data generating process is 
$$Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \pi + \epsilon_i.$$
I have experimental data from two treatment intensities, $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$, and a control $(\pi=0)$. Suppose 1/3 of treated individuals are assigned to T1, 1/6 are assigned to T2 and 1/2 are assigned to the pure control. I am interested in measuring the pooled treatment effect across both treatment intensities. Let $T_i = 1\{\pi_i>0\}$. 
$$Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_2 T_i + \epsilon_i$$
The true effect corresponds to $$\beta_2 = \frac 2 3 \beta_1  \pi_1+ \frac 1 3 \beta_1 \pi_2$$ 
and the minimum detectable effect for $\beta_2$ at significance level $\alpha$ and power $\kappa$ is
$$MDE=(t_{\alpha} + t_{1-\kappa}) 2 \sqrt{ \frac{\sigma^2}{N}}$$
where $\sigma^2$ is the variance of $\epsilon$ and $N$ is the total sample size.

Now suppose I want to weight the data so that the observations with intensity $\pi_2$ have double the weight of the $\pi_1$ observations. This will yield a measure of the effect:
$$\beta_{2 weighted} = \frac 1 2 \beta_1  \pi_1+ \frac 1 2 \beta_1 \pi_2$$ 
How do I adjust the minimum detectable effect to account for the sample weights?

Comment: "Now suppose I want to weight the data so that the observations with intensity π2 have double the weight of the π1 observations." - Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Policy analysis question that depends on that weighting scheme.

Comment: I don't follow. Is it a sensitivity analysis as to possible weighting schemes?

Comment: We chose the existing design with unequal allocation across treatment intensity due to the relative importance of measuring the effects individually at each treatment intensity. For the pooled analysis, we want to estimate an effect that gives equal weight to each intensity to facilitate comparisons with other studies.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, unequal weighting reduces precision and power. One easy way to think about it is that, say, the maximum likelihood estimates of the normal mean have equal weights of $1/n$, so anything that deviates from that uniform weighting scheme cannot be optimal. Same can be said about BLUEs. (But this is not to say that equal weighting always makes better sense than unequal weighting; robust statistics starts with the premise that robustness is a more important property than efficiency, to which most economists would subscribe. But I digress.)

Efficiency losses are characterized by *design effects* (due to [Kish 1965](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471109495)). For unequal weights, the design effect is ([Korn and Graubard 1999, sec. 4.4](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9781118032619.ch4/summary))
$$
\mbox{UWE DEFF} = \frac{n\sum_i w_i^2}{\bigl(\sum_i w_i\bigr)^2}
$$
and the effective sample size is 
$$
n_{\rm eff} = \frac{\bigl(\sum_i w_i\bigr)^2}{\sum_i w_i^2}
$$
So if two thirds of the weights are equal to 1, and the remaining third, to 2, you have
$$
n_{\rm eff} = \frac{\bigl(1\cdot 2n/3 + 2 \cdot n/3 )^2}{1 \cdot 2n/3 + 4 \cdot n/3}=\frac{16n^2/9}{2n}=\frac{8n}{9}
$$
That would be the quantity to go into your denominator.